# Добавить дополнительную надпись в всплывающее окно chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, диаграммы, vue3, chart.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть график от chartjs

Можно ли к узлу (в данном примере к бару) прикрепить ещё дополнительную запись какую-то?  Пытаюсь и не могу найти способ прикрепить к data[] ещё дополнительную запись. Например, если бар отображает время (как в моём случае), то я бы хотел вернуть с бэка хуманизированное время и показать его во всплывающем элементе у бара

соответственно для каждого бара это будет своё значение точно также как и data

В моём случае я пытаюсь реализовать это всё на vue ^2.7.14 с помощью пакета vue-chart.js

Comment: На всякий случай уточняю. В dataset прописывается массив data[] и по нему отрисовывается диаграмма, я хочу добавить такой же массив с разными доп. надписями которые будут крепиться к каждому элементу data[] по порядку